# count users data by referrals

Tags: mysql

I  am trying to write a query to count all similer value form referrals number column by referred_by.
Here is my table;

```
    +----+-------------+-------------+-------+
    | id | referralsNo | referred_by | total |
    +----+-------------+-------------+-------+
    | 35 |           1 | 0           |   300 |
    | 40 |           2 | 35          |   600 |
    | 44 |           2 | 41          |   600 |
    | 45 |           1 | 36          |   300 |
    +----+-------------+-------------+-------+
```

I want to collect  referrals no if 1 is two time then its show 2 and 2 is show two time then its show 4,
I using this query

```
 select count(referralsNo) from referral_view group by referralsNO;
```

And output of this

```
+--------------------+
| count(referralsNo) |
+--------------------+
|                  2 |
|                  2 |
+--------------------+
```

Any one help me to get Data;

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's the problem with your query?

Comment: Maybe you want `SUM(referralsNo)` and `GROUP BY referred_by`?

Comment: Barmar@I need  if referrals no is 1 then sum of 1 value and if 2  is three time then show 6, and one is two time then show 2

Comment: That's what you wrote in the question, saying the same thing doesn't make it any clearer.

Comment: So you want a sum, not a count.

Comment: Barmar @yes Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You want a sum, not a count.

```
SELECT SUM(referralsNo)
FROM referral_view
GROUP BY referralsNo
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9XU9c35MVQEo9ifyDvgf84/0)